# Date cell mask doesn't come correctly

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm reading an .xlsx file with Apache POI that has a cell with the following value: **Jan/17**.

But when I do check the cell variable with

```java
String pattern = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()
```

pattern return wrong mask: **mmm-yy** and wrong value **Jan-17**.

- I tried to use DataFormatter, but return the same error
- I tried to use CellDateFormatter, but return the same error too
- Replace the character "-" to "/" is not an option because it can be used "-" in file.

Comment: The value **Jan-17** is obtained when using formatters

Comment: This is not an error but is how Microsoft Excel localizes the date formats. The file always stores formats in en_US locale. That is `mmm-yy` for this format. The Excel GUI then interprets that format different dependent on the Excel and/or Windows locale settings. So the question is: What  Excel and/or Windows locale settings are you using which interprets the en_US date format `mmm-yy` so, that it shows Jan/17?

Comment: so changing the locale in the excel settings would solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error but is how Microsoft Excel localizes the date formats. Excel files always store formats in en_US locale. That is `mmm-yy` for this format.  It is the Excel built-in format with ID 17 (0x11, "mmm-yy"). See [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html). It gets applied when user inputs only month and year in a cell. For example: 1/17, which is month 1 in year 17.

In my German Excel this looks like so using German Windows locale:

[image]

The Excel GUI then interprets that format different dependent on the Excel and/or Windows locale settings. For example, if I change the Windows locale settings to Portuguese (Brasil) in Control Panel - Time and Region:

[image]

then it looks like so:

[image]

Note, nothing has changed in Excel file. Only Windows locale settings have changed.

Unfortunately Apache POI `DataFormatter` fails to interpret locale settings exactly like Excel does.

Following code interprets the Excel built-in format with ID 17 (0x11, "mmm-yy") as `mmm-yy` = Jan-17 using en_US locale. This is correct. But it interprets it as `mmm.-yy` = Jan.-17 using de_DE locale. This is wrong, should be `mmm yy` = Jan 17 like in Excel. And using pt_BR locale it interprets it as `mmm.-yy`= jan.-17. This is wrong too, should be `mmm/yy` = jan/17 like in Excel.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"));
  
  // up to apache poi 5.1.0 a FormulaEvaluator is needed to evaluate the formulas while using DataFormatter
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
  
  //DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
  //DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("de", "DE"));
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR"));
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String pattern = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
    System.out.println(pattern);   
    //String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator); // up to apache poi 5.1.0
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell); // from apache poi 5.2.0 on 
    System.out.println(value);
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

To overcome this incorrectness in Apache POI, one could add a special data format for the `mmm-yy` to the `DataFormatter` dependent on used locale. This can be achieved using [public void addFormat(java.lang.String excelFormatStr, java.text.Format format)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#addFormat-java.lang.String-java.text.Format-).

Complete example again:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"));
  
  // up to apache poi 5.1.0 a FormulaEvaluator is needed to evaluate the formulas while using DataFormatter
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
  
  //LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
  //LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(new java.util.Locale("de", "DE"));
  LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(); // uses user locale set
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(new java.util.Locale("de", "DE"))) {
   dataFormatter.addFormat("mmm-yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM yy", new java.util.Locale("en", "US")));
  } else if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"))) {
   dataFormatter.addFormat("mmm-yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yy", new java.util.Locale("en", "US")));
  } else if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR"))) {
   dataFormatter.addFormat("mmm-yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yy", new java.util.Locale("en", "US")));
  }
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String pattern = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
    System.out.println(pattern);   
    //String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator); // up to apache poi 5.1.0
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell); // from apache poi 5.2.0 on 
    System.out.println(value);
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Note, the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` always gets created usig en_US locale. Else, month abbreviations may be followed by a dot. For example: Jan. 17 or Jan./17.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically it, I had to make some adjustments because "Dez" becomes "Dec" in en_US